# PHP getting values of the objects by key inside array

Tags: php, arrays, object

Hi all I have an array "$decodedData" of object from json data.

```
var_export($decodedData);
```

returns next:

```
array ( 0 => array ( 'number' => '2', 'type' => 'accs', ), 1 => array ( 'number' => '5', 'type' => 'accs', ), )
```

I'm trying to output all the "numbers" values:

```
foreach ($decodedData as $number)
{
    echo implode(',', $number);
}
```

but I'm getting "type" values either

```
2,accs5,accs
```

How can I get rid of those?

Comment: Have you read the PHP docs for [foreach](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)? There is a way to get the key and value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map) to accomplish that.

The first parameter is a callback function that will receive each element and return something to replace it with. In this case, we are returning the `number` key of each element.

```
$result = array_map(function($val) {
    return $val['number'];
}, $array);

echo implode(',', $result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looping through an array of arrays, so `$number` is returning a complete array, not the number value. To access the number value of each, do something like this:

```
foreach ($decodedData as $number=>$val){
    echo implode(',', $val['number']);
}
```